# optimizing awk command for large file

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have these functions to process a 2GB text file. I'm splitting it into 6 parts for simultaneous processing but it is still taking 4+ hours.

What else can I try make the script faster?

A bit of details:

1. I feed my input csv into a while loop to be read line by line.
2. I grabbed the values from the csv line from 4 fields in the read2col function
3. The awk in my mainf function takes the values from read2col and do some arithmetic calculation. I'm rounding the result to 2 decimal places. Then, print the line to a text file.

Sample data:

```
"111","2018-08-24","01:21","ZZ","AAA","BBB","0","","","ZZ","ZZ111","ZZ110","2018-10-12","07:00","2018-10-12","08:05","2018-10-19","06:30","2018-10-19","09:35","ZZZZ","ZZZZ","A","B","146.00","222.26","76.26","EEE","abc","100.50","45.50","0","E","ESSENTIAL","ESSENTIAL","4","4","7","125","125"
```

---

Script:

```
read2col()
{
is_one_way=$(echo "$line"| awk -F'","' '{print $7}')
price_outbound=$(echo "$line"| awk -F'","' '{print $30}')
price_exc=$(echo "$line"| awk -F'","' '{print $25}')
tax=$(echo "$line"| awk -F'","' '{print $27}')
price_inc=$(echo "$line"| awk -F'","' '{print $26}')
}


#################################################
#for each line in the csv
mainf()
{
cd $infarepath

while read -r line; do
        #read the value of csv fields into variables
        read2col

        if [[ $is_one_way == 0 ]]; then
                if [[ $price_outbound > 0 ]]; then
                        #calculate price inc and print the entire line to txt file
                        echo $line | awk -v CONVFMT='%.2f' -v pout=$price_outbound -v tax=$tax -F'","' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} {$25=pout;$26=(pout+(tax / 2)); print}' >>"$csvsplitfile".tmp
                else
                        #divide price ecx and inc by 2 if price outbound is not greater than 0
                        echo $line | awk -v CONVFMT='%.2f' -v pexc=$price_exc -v pinc=$price_inc -F'","' 'BEGIN {OFS = FS} {$25=(pexc / 2);$26=(pinc /2); print}' >>"$csvsplitfile".tmp
                fi
        else
                echo $line >>"$csvsplitfile".tmp
        fi

done < $csvsplitfile
}
```

Comment: Why not write a python/perl/etc. script to do this? It'll be a lot faster, and more robust (Assuming you use an actual CSV parsing library, of course).

Comment: @Shawn : `perl` ?? The language where being lax is the default, and that strictness needs to be declared, as opposed to the other way around ? And I dunno where you get notions `python` is fast …. like … at all. Most of my`awk / perl / python` 3-way benchmarking ended up needing to manually `kill -9` off `python` after 45 mins for what the other 2 accomplished in a minute or two.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The *first* thing you should do is stop invoking *six* subshells for running `awk` for every single line of input. Let's do some quick, back-of-the-envelope calculations.

Assuming your input lines are about 292 characters (as per you example), a 2G file will consist of a little over 7.3 million lines. That means you are starting and stopping a whopping *forty-four million* processes.

And, while Linux admirably handles `fork` and `exec` as efficiently as possible, it's not without cost:

```
pax$ time for i in {1..44000000} ; do true ; done
real 1m0.946s
```

In addition, `bash` hasn't really been optimised for this sort of processing, its design leads to sub-optimal behaviour for this specific use case. For details on this, see [this excellent answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) over on one of our sister sites.

An analysis of the two methods of file processing (one program reading an entire file (each line has just `hello` on it), and `bash` reading it a line at a time) is shown below. The two commands used to get the timings were:

```
time ( cat somefile >/dev/null )
time ( while read -r x ; do echo $x >/dev/null ; done <somefile )
```

For varying file sizes (`user+sys` time, averaged over a few runs), it's quite interesting:

```
# of lines   cat-method   while-method
----------   ----------   ------------
     1,000       0.375s         0.031s
    10,000       0.391s         0.234s
   100,000       0.406s         1.994s
 1,000,000       0.391s        19.844s
10,000,000       0.375s       205.583s
44,000,000       0.453s       889.402s
```

From this, it appears that the `while` method can hold its own for smaller data sets, it *really* does not scale well.

---

Since `awk` itself has ways to do calculations and formatted output, processing the file with one *single* `awk` script, rather than your `bash`/multi-`awk`-per-line combination, will make the cost of creating all those processes and line-based delays go away.

This script would be a good first attempt, let's call it `prog.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FMT = "%.2f"
    OFS = FS
}
{
    isOneWay=$7
    priceOutbound=$30
    priceExc=$25
    tax=$27
    priceInc=$26

    if (isOneWay == 0) {
        if (priceOutbound > 0) {
            $25 = sprintf(FMT, priceOutbound)
            $26 = sprintf(FMT, priceOutbound + tax / 2)
        } else {
            $25 = sprintf(FMT, priceExc / 2)
            $26 = sprintf(FMT, priceInc / 2)
        }
    }
    print
}
```

You just run that *single* `awk` script with:

```
awk -F'","' -f prog.awk data.txt
```

With the test data you provided, here's the before and after, with markers for field numbers 25 and 26:

```
                                                                                                                                                                                      <-25->   <-26->
"111","2018-08-24","01:21","ZZ","AAA","BBB","0","","","ZZ","ZZ111","ZZ110","2018-10-12","07:00","2018-10-12","08:05","2018-10-19","06:30","2018-10-19","09:35","ZZZZ","ZZZZ","A","B","146.00","222.26","76.26","EEE","abc","100.50","45.50","0","E","ESSENTIAL","ESSENTIAL","4","4","7","125","125"
"111","2018-08-24","01:21","ZZ","AAA","BBB","0","","","ZZ","ZZ111","ZZ110","2018-10-12","07:00","2018-10-12","08:05","2018-10-19","06:30","2018-10-19","09:35","ZZZZ","ZZZZ","A","B","100.50","138.63","76.26","EEE","abc","100.50","45.50","0","E","ESSENTIAL","ESSENTIAL","4","4","7","125","125"
```

Comment: In your test script you use `echo $x`. I would prefer `echo "$x"` or skip the additonal parsing with `printf "%s\n" "$x"`. Your conclusion is still valid, just a difference in the times.

Comment: My solution was over engineered. I didnt know you could store an awk function in a file an run it from the command line

Comment: @user2189312, I once heard a quip that "awk was for C developers who couldn't be bothered running the compiler" :-)

Comment: @user2189312 to be clear - not an awk **function**, an awk **script**. You can't store an awk function in a file and run it from the command line (without providing the rest of the script to call it). You're actually running `awk` from the command line and passing it a file containing a script to interpret of course.

Comment: nitpick - don't use all upper case for user defined variables so they don't look like builtin variables and can't clash with builtin variables. When I saw `FMT = "%.2f"` I at first thought you were setting [OFMT](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#OFMT) and then had to look up the manual for a variable named `FMT` before finally realizing it was a user-defined variable!

Comment: Ed, that's my naming style, I prefer to be able to tell the difference between variables and 'constants'. There's no actual clash here though I suppose you could use something like `MYFMT` if you wanted to be more obvious. I don't find that necessary myself

Comment: @paxdiablo :`"awk was for C developers who couldn't be bothered running the compiler"` ….  the proper way should be `awk is for people who want nearest to raw hardware performance without wasting time worrying about C's mallocs pitfalls, python's library bloat and one-liner extreme unfriendliness, Ruby's verbosity, perl's lack of default strictness, and C++'s identity crisis of not knowing whether it wants to be a very high level language or a very low language thus playing safe by being all things to all people`